# Await call causing unexpected behavior on instance attribute

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I am having some trouble to figure out why uncommenting the `await asyncio.sleep(1)` causes `Test` to be printed 10 times. It seems that the initialization of `val` attribute is failing when using async.

Shouldn't the initialization be respected and print only once, as it is the same instance. How can address this behavior when `awaitable` calls are present?

```
class TestAsync:

    def __init__(self):
        self.val = None

    async def some_fun(self):
        if not self.val:
            # await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Magic line
            print('Test')
            self.val = 10

async def main(loop):
    a = TestAsync()
    tasks = [a.some_fun() for _ in range(10)]
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cur_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    cur_loop.run_until_complete(main(cur_loop))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asyncio` doesn't let you stop thinking about concurrency issues. You're running into pretty much exactly the same issue you would have had with threads.

Each `some_fun` coroutine that sees a falsy value of `self.val` continues into the body of the `if` statement. How many coroutines see such a value depends on how many coroutines reach the `if` test before one of them sets `self.val` to `10`.

Without the `sleep`, the first coroutine sets `self.val` to `10` immediately, without giving any others a chance to intervene. With the `sleep`, each coroutine goes to sleep and lets others run, and all of them see `None` before any of them changes the value.

Comment: It was such a basic problem. I was unable to figure out. I will use some sort of synchronization to initialize the value then leave all concurrent work to get done.

Answer (score 2):

This is totally not the same problem as in threads.

All coroutines run in the same thread, there isn't any multithreads race problem in coroutines.

But the problem is the switch of coroutines. When you use `await asyncio.sleep(1)`, this await will cause context switch from one coroutine to another.

Let's take two coroutines as example: `C1` and `C2`. So at first there is an execution queue for these two coroutines: `Q{C1, C2}`. Then `C1` is popped to execute, and without `await`, there isn't any switch, so `C1` will be executed fully. Next, `C2` is popped to execute.

So the order of execution is `C1 -> C2`. Which is totally linear.

But when there is `await`, it will cause switch. Which means `C1` will be stopped and inserted to the end of queue. Then `C2` will be popped to execute. While `C2` will also be stopped at that line and inserted to the end of queue. Next `C1` will be popped again and executed fully.

So the order of execution is `C1(before await) -> C2(before await) -> C1(the rest) -> C2(the rest)`.

Obviously, all your coroutines will be stopped after checking `val`. Which is the core problem. This is not a problem about concurrency race, but a problem about really understanding how `await` will affect your program.